# Why does $x^Tx=||x||^2$?

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, vectors, normed-spaces

How can we prove that "We know that for any vector x, $x^Tx=||x||^2$. Thus , ..... "

The way I am thinking that while $x^T$  is the transpose of x, then we cross product with itself using $x^T$, which results in a symmetric matrix, R. So R is a square matrix.  How can we jump from a square matrix to $||x||^2, $ where ||x|| supposed to mean the normal of x, then we square it with 2?

Comment: Write it out in coordinates, it follows directly

Comment: What should I write it out in coordinates ? the square matrix?

Comment: You confused $x^Tx$ with $xx^T$. Vectors are normally considered as vertical, not horizontal.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek ok seem like you are right about that $x^Tx$ may not equal to $xx^T$,  but where is wrong with my reasoning thought ? given that vector x is a column vector, then after it transpose, shouldn't it become a horizontal vector?

Comment: You should take the product in such order that you get a scalar (or 1x1 matrix), as in the answer. Otherwise, as you yourself noticed, the equality does not make much sense.

Comment: Note that when multplying matrices $AB$ the result has as many rows as $A$ and as many columns as $B$. Thus $x^Tx$ is a 1x1 matrix and can be considered as scalar...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x=\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\...\\x_n\end{bmatrix}$ and therefore $x^T = \begin{bmatrix}x_1 & ... &x_n\end{bmatrix}$.

If you evaluate $x\cdot x^T$ you multiply the rows of x (just one entry) with the columns of $x^T$ with also just one entry. This gives you the matrix. This is also called a dyadic product.

If you evaluate $x^T\cdot x$ you multiply the one single row of $x^T$ with the single column of $x$ to give you just a single number. And by some kind of definition, this equals the squared length of the vector in a euclidian sense.

So: Just write $x$ and x^T$ as matrices and use the usual way of multiplying them.

Comment: Would you please confirm that: if we evaluates $x  \ \ dot \ \  x^T $, the result is also a single number? , a bit confused by your word, "This gives you the matrix. This is also called the dyadic product."

Comment: If you write this as the product of two matrices, you mutiply every column (there are $n$ single indenepende tcolumns in $x$) with every row of $x^T$ (there are $n$ of those). This gives you $n\times n$ single numbers of the form $x_ix_j$ that form an $n\times n$ matrix.

Comment: but in wiki, Normal matrix

"A square matrix A is called normal if   ${ A^{{T} }A=AA^{{T} }}$,  , i.e. if it commutes with its transpose. ."  seem like  $A ^T A = A A ^T $ should return the same type of result.  But according to you answer, the first one is a matrix, the second one is a scalar .

Comment: That is because the matrix $x$ is not normal (and not even square)! The definition of "normal matrix" has to with the eigenvectors of the matrix and is not to be confused with the terms "norm", which is a totally different concept and has to do with the lengths.

Comment: finally, started making some  sense, What would you say if we have another vector y, where y = [$y_1$, ...$y_n$],  when ($x^Ty$) should yield $\langle x, y \rangle$ , and the result of $\langle x, y \rangle$  should be a scalar, (?)

Comment: Yes, $x^Ty$ is a scalar. This is called a "scalar product" (to be exactly: One specific scalar product, as it can be generalized).

Answer (score 1):

By definition $\|x\|^2=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2$. On the other hand, if we treat $x$ as a $n\times 1$ matrix (and therefore $x^T$ is a $1\times n$ matrix) then we can use matrix multiplication to obtain a $1\times 1$ matrix whose only entry equals the dot product of $x$ with itself, i.e.
$$
x^Tx=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2.
$$

Comment: Where does $||x||^2$ means, is my understand correct, it is the norm of a vector , then we square it.   When you said  n x 1 matrix, is the matrix vertical, as one column with n rows ;  then $x^T$ is the horizontal matrix with n columns, then using the matrix multiplications to obtain a n x n matrix,   then we can calculate the norm of the n x n matrix,?

Comment: In english, "norm" and "normal" mean different things. "norm" means the length of the vector. It is by definition the square root of the sum. So when you square, all that remains is the sum of the squares. I interpreted $x$ as a horizontal (row) vector with $n$ rows and $1$ column, so that $x^Tx$ as you wrote makes sense. The other way $xx^T$ makes sense too if $x$ is a column vector instead. Either way we never get a $n\times n$ matrix. That wouldn't work since we would not have any summation involved, only products.